# Trying to speed up recursive examination of directories/files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will recursively descend through a directory and report any file or directory that has a permission that is *not* inherited.

I feel like I'm close with this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\xyzzy' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $fullpath = $_.FullName
        
    (get-acl -path $_.FullName).Access | ForEach-Object {
       if ($_.IsInherited -ne 'True') {
         write-output $fullpath
       }
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but it is horribly slow on a large directory tree.  Anyone have some suggestions for speeding this up?

Thanks!

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? Also, `$_.IsInherited -ne 'True'` should be either `-not $_.IsInherited` or `$_.IsInherited -ne $True`

Comment: Not unless you can use -filter to narrow it down.

Comment: My Powershell version is 5.1.19041.2364

Comment: Corrected the test for an inherited file.  No change in behavior.

Comment: Please define "slow" and "large". How many files/directories and how long does it take?

Comment: I had to do a lot of file validation and searches for logs in the past. Powershell is just too high level for performance. Winapi is the way to go, so either c++ or c# and PInvoke. Well that is if you want to traverse a directory tree in milliseconds or seconds and not in minutes or hours.

Comment: "large" is 3.2 million files in 618 folders.  And I've got some larger than that to process...  For that 3.2 million file directory, it doesn't finish overnight.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be much faster than what you're currently doing, it uses a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0) to traverse the directories instead of `Get-ChildItem` and, since you're using PowerShell 5.1, the [`GetAccessControl()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-io-fileinfo-getaccesscontrol) instance methods of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` can be used instead of `Get-Acl`.

Lastly here:

```bash
(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Access | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.IsInherited -ne $true) {
        Write-Output $fullpath
    }
}
```

Since you're only interested in getting the absolute path of a file of folder if there is **any non inherited rule**, the above loop should be stopped as soon as the condition is met, there is no need to enumerate all rules.

**Note, this code includes hidden files and folders**.

```
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue('C:\xyzzy')

class FilterAccessRules {
    static [string] NotInherited([System.IO.FileSystemInfo] $Instance) {
        # enumerate each Access Rule
        foreach($rule in $Instance.GetAccessControl().Access) {
            # if this rule is not Inherited
            if(-not $rule.IsInherited) {
                # there is no need to keep checking next rules
                # output the absolute path and end here
                return $Instance.FullName
            }
        }

        # else, output null
        return $null
    }
}

while($queue.Count) {
    $target = $queue.Dequeue()

    try {
        if($path = [FilterAccessRules]::NotInherited($target)) {
            $path
        }
    }
    catch { }

    try {
        $enum = $target.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
    }
    catch {
        # if this folder could not be enumerated,
        # go next
        continue
    }

    foreach($item in $enum) {
        if($item -is [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
            if($path = [FilterAccessRules]::NotInherited($item)) {
                $path
            }
            continue
        }

        $queue.Enqueue($item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To offer an alternative to [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75512283/45375):

It may not be as fast, but may be fast enough in practice, and has the advantage of being conceptually simpler and more concise:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -PipelineVariable item -LiteralPath C:\xyzzy -Recurse |
  Get-Acl |
  Where-Object   { $_.Access.IsInherited -contains $false } |
  ForEach-Object { $item.FullName }
```

- The above avoids calling `Get-Acl` *once for each input file* and instead uses a *single* invocation that takes its input directly from the pipelin, which should significantly speed up the operation.
- `$_.Access.IsInherited` uses [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to return all `.Inherited` property values across all rules returned by `.Access`, and `-contains $false` tests if at least one value is `$false`.
- Note the use of the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) to store the current file-system item, as output by `Get-ChildItem` in self-chosen variable `$item`, making it available for use in script blocks in later pipeline segments.

  - Note: You don't strictly need `-PipeLineVariable` here, but it makes the full path (`.FullName` property) of the item at hand readily available. While the `Get-Acl` output objects themselves have an (ETS) `.Path` property, its value starts with a PowerShell [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix, namely `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`, which would have to be removed (which you could do with `$_.Path -replace '^[^:]+::'`)

---

If you don't care about *streaming* output - notably to see output *as it is being produced* - you can further speed up the above as follows:

```bash
(
  Get-ChildItem -PipelineVariable item -LiteralPath C:\xyzzy -Recurse |
  Get-Acl
).Where({ $_.Access.IsInherited -contains $false }).Path -replace '^[^:]+::'
```